# WPF Form within a Windows Forms project

Tags: wpf, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I have an existing **Windows Forms** project.

Can I create an additional **WPF/XAML Window** (a full new window) within such a project?

Visual Studio does not offer that option, but I think that should be possible somehow, at least via code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this job you must add this references to your Win-Form projects:

- PresentationCore
- PresentationFramework
- WindowsBase
- System.Xaml

[Help link](http://tech.pro/tutorial/799/wpf-tutorial-using-wpf-in-winforms)

And to host WPF windows in WinForm or win32 apps you will need this line before you `.Show()` your Wpf Window:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(myWpfWindow);
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa348549.aspx

Helpful link: [Mixing WPF and WinForms](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/mixing-wpf-and-winforms/)